# Login redirect URL error in Redmine 2.0.3

Tags: redmine

I have installed Redmine 2.0.3 on my server and it all works fine except that when you login the URL gets messed up so it fails to redirect properly. If you manually enter the correct URL after logging in it works ok.

The URL I get is:

`http://redmine.mydomain.comhttp%3a%2f%2fredmine.mydomain.com%2f`

Where is this URL generated / how do I fix it?

Thanks.

Martin

Answer (score 2):

My setup has a "Main" Apache httpd with SSL enabled and mod_proxy to a seperate apache instance for Redmine v2.1.2.

I had the described troubles which I believe is Rails and not Redmine itself.

Log from production:

```
Started GET "/redmine/projects/test/issues/new" for 127.0.0.1 at Tue Dec 11 
07:31:31 -0800 2012
Processing by IssuesController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"project_id"=>"test"}
  Current user: anonymous
Redirected to http://myserver/redmine/login?back_url=http%3A%2F%2Fmyserver%2F
redmine%2Fprojects%2Ftest%2Fissues%2Fnew
Filter chain halted as :authorize rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 155ms (ActiveRecord: 98.4ms)

Started GET "/redmine/login?back_url=http%253A%252F%252Fmyserver%252Fredmine%252F
projects%252Ftest%252Fissues%252Fnew" for 127.0.0.1 at Tue Dec 11 07:31:31 -0800 
2012
Processing by AccountController#login as HTML
  Parameters: {"back_url"=>"http%3A%2F%2Fmyserver%2Fredmine%2Fprojects%2Ftest%2F
  issues%2Fnew"}
  Current user: anonymous
  Rendered account/login.html.erb within layouts/base (11.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 399ms (Views: 351.9ms | ActiveRecord: 37.7ms)
Started POST "/redmine/login" for 127.0.0.1 at Tue Dec 11 07:32:17 -0800 2012
Processing by AccountController#login as HTML
  Parameters: {"username"=>"speroshiropetto", "back_url"=>"http%3A%2F%2Fmyserver
  %2Fredmine%2Fprojects%2Ftest%2Fissues%2Fnew", "login"=>"Login »", "utf8"=>"?", 
  "authenticity_token"=>"D4wruy76o/adfhafnen30kS6b2FtOQIaiFdtzbMxzs=", 
  "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}
  Current user: anonymous
Successful authentication for 'speroshiropetto' from 127.0.0.1 at Tue Dec 11 
15:32:17 UTC 2012
Redirected to http://myserverhttp%3A%2F%2Fmyserver%2Fredmine%2Fprojects%2Ftest%2F
issues%2Fnew
Completed 302 Found in 356ms (ActiveRecord: 176.4ms)

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Adding the following into the Redmine Apache config helped out.

`RequestHeader set X_FORWARDED_PROTO 'https'`